# Custom Buttons for Google Drawing Manager

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api

can we design my own custom button for the Drawing manager?

According to API

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DrawingManagerOptions

we can customize only the symbols which is drawn out of the drawing manager.

for example i need to make this drawing manager look like Google Map maker

http://www.google.co.in/mapmaker

Comment: You can only use Point and Line to built into the API see http://jsfiddle.net/yV6xv/35/ but you can change symbol markers after the drawing is complete (milliseconds).

Comment: ya markers i can change.. but i need to change the icon which i can see in the Drawing toolbar.. like in google mapmaker

Answer (score 2):

Try using CSS:

`#map-canvas div { cursor: pointer !important }`